# detecting network communities using walktrap using a large number of steps

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I am trying to find communities within my network using the R implementation of "walktrap." My network consists of about 300 nodes, and is densely connected. The normal procedure is to use 4 or 5 steps to specify the length of the random walks, but I tried using 10000 steps just to see what would happen:

```
a=walktrap.community(g, weights = NULL, steps = 10000, 
    merges =TRUE, modularity = TRUE, membership = TRUE)
```

The resulting dendrogram looks more meaningful than the one with just 4 steps. But I do not understand why I am getting a dendrogram at all. According to the Pons and Latapy paper, it seems like the distance between any two nodes in the limit of infinite steps goes to zero (r_{ij}). My network (g) is directed, but is says in the manual that direction is ignored in the algorithm.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I guess you would need to either ask the authors of the paper, or check the source code of the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the paper, then you will find the "real" name of the paper is actually,
Computing communities in large networks using "short" random walks. 
Property 1 from the paper tells us that the distance between vertex i and vertex j only depends on the degree of vertex j when step is infinite.
[image: Property 1]

So, if you set step very large and your graph is a dense(although I don't know how densely your graph is) network. The distance between vertex No.1 and other 299 vertices is the same. And it will end up with only one community.